# SQL - Group By 3 columns in same table with average

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called properties which has 2 columns:

1. prop_type (posible values: department, house, land, etc)
2. prop_exclusive (posible values: Exclusive, Non Exclusive)

I need to group records by **prop_type** and get the **average** amount of **prop_exclusive** column.

The expected result is:

[image]

How does my sql syntax should be?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really need to show averages as percentages, you could modify Gordon's solution as below. Having said that, I strongly suggest you keep averages in numeric data type and format the output in the presentation layer instead.

```
select proptype,
       concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'Exclusive' ) * 100, 0),'%') as ratio_exclusive,
       concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'Nonexclusive' )* 100, 0),'%') as ratio_nonexclusive
from t
group by proptype
```

Comment: Thanks @Mithrandir, this is what I was expecting. Based on your suggestion, you said that better remove the % contactenation and manage that in UI, right?

Comment: @BelisarioPeró If this is part of a larger process where the output of this script gets re-used --e.g. a where/join condition on those ratio columns that are now cast to string due to concat, then there is potential for inaccuracies and inefficiencies. But if this is a one off script that directly feeds into a UI as is for display purpose only, it might not hurt to convert it your liking. Having said that, if you are able to format the output in the presentation layer, you should do so

Answer (score 2):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select proptype,
       avg( prop_exclusive = 'Exclusive' ) as ratio_exclusive,
       avg( prop_exclusive = 'Nonexclusive' ) as ratio_nonexclusive
from t
group by proptype
```

Comment: Thanks @Gorn Linoff, I will have to convert that ouput into %. Great approach thanks!

Comment: @BelisarioPeró . . . Just multiply by 100 if that is what you really want.